# Getting filename between multipal special characters using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fetch the file names which are in between multiple special character like '$$'  ( example  $$yaktocat.png$$) , i think it's better to ignore single special character $, if not we cannot use that character inside the file.

sample data

```
img src="$$yaktocat.png$$" alt="this is yaktocat image"
```

Regex trying to use

```
(\$+?(.*?)\$+?)
```

but still that match the single instance also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
\$\$([^$]*)\$\$
```

Now the only captured group, `([^$]*)`, will have the desired filename (e.g. `yaktocat.png`), surrounded by `$$`s.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT0rM9/4)